# xgboost feature importance in R

Tags: xgboost

theres 8 columns input layer and binary classification labels.
i have made xgboost classification model with those, and its optimized colsample_bytree hyperparameter was 0.75
so in 8 inputs, only 6 inputs were used in this model.

but when i check feature importance of model, there's 8 inputs and all of it has frequency score.

i don't understand this. why 6 inputs are used but 8 columns are effects to model?

[here's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jgQL.png)

Comment: Your assumption "its optimized colsample_bytree hyperparameter was 0.75 so in 8 inputs, only 6 inputs were used in this model" is not correct - for each tree, 75% of each variable was used, then the trees were combined giving you feature importance for all 8 variables

Comment: ahhh i understand. thank you so much